# Codeigniter errors appearing when I get data array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, controller, models

I have a model which passes one record to my controller but I keep receiving these two errors

> Message: Missing argument 1 for Quotes_model::get_records(), called in
>   /home/digibite/public_html/development/quote/application/controllers/welcome.php
>   on line 12 and defined
>
> Message: Missing argument 2 for Quotes_model::get_records(), called in
>   /home/digibite/public_html/development/quote/application/controllers/welcome.php
>   on line 12 and defined

I have been playing around with this for almost an hour and can't get my head around it.

My model

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Quotes_model extends CI_Model{

  function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
  }

  function get_records($limit, $offset){
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('quotes')
             ->join('authors', 'authors.id = quotes.author_id')
             ->join('genre', 'genre.id = quotes.id')
             ->order_by('id', 'RANDOM')
             ->limit($limit, $offset);
    $data = array();
    $data[] = array (

      'title' => $row->title,
      'slug' => $row->slug,
      'meta_keys' => $row->meta_keys,
      'meta_description' => $row->meta_description,
      'content' => $row->content,
      'views' => $row->views,  
    );

    return $data;


  }
}
```

And this is my controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {


        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('quotes_model');
        $data['quote']= $this->quotes_model->get_records();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because, you are not passing any arguments through the function in controller.

```
$data['quote']= $this->quotes_model->get_records();
                                                 ^
```

and you are trying to call the arguments ( you are supposed to pass to the model ) in the query.

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('quotes')
             ->join('authors', 'authors.id = quotes.author_id')
             ->join('genre', 'genre.id = quotes.id')
             ->order_by('id', 'RANDOM')
             ->limit($limit, $offset);
                     ^         ^
```

Comment: sorry im a newbie can you please guide me more? anywhere i pass these arguments i get  a different error, what im trying to achieve is to get one random record, pass it to my controller to redirect me to that page based on slug record

Comment: What error are you getting when you pass the arguments?